# How we could make a stack file from hundreds of img files, in R programming language?

Tags: r, image, stack

I have around 184 .img image files per year. 
Their name is like these:

```
mod11a1_2009-03-30.lst_day_1km.img
mod11a1_2009-03-31.lst_day_1km.img
mod11a1_2009-04-01.lst_day_1km.img
```

.
.
.

I am going to put all of those .img files, into 1 stack image with the same format:

```
mod11a1_2009_lst_day_1km.img
```

And **generate** the final stack image as an .img file in my working directory.

I wonder if someone could help me to do so, **using R programming language**.
As I am new in R, I would be very grateful if you could help me in detail.

FYI:
I am using R-Studio.
My working directory is 'M:/2009_stack'

Comment: Take a look at the `raster` package, which has functions to build stacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to install and load the `raster` package:

```
install.packages("raster", dependencies=TRUE)
library(raster)
```

Then change your working directory to the file location:

```
setwd("M:/2009_stack")
```

Create a raster stack out of your files:

```
myStack <- stack(list.files(pattern="\\.img$"))
```

If you want to export an .IMG file into your working directory:

```
writeRaster(myStack,"mod11a1_2009_lst_day_1km.img", format="HFA")
```

For more information on the used `raster` functions have a look [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/stack) or [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/writeRaster).

Comment: You may want to edit your `list.files()` call to include a wildcard (e.g. `list.files(pattern="\\.img$")`) to weed out any non-image files (such as pyramid, statistics or metadata files) that are often present.  Otherwise exactly the solution I'd have proposed.

Comment: Thank you so much maRtin. Great help. Now, I can save my time, incredibly. Thanks to others for their comments, as well.

Comment: Hi maRtin, Could you please have a look to this question, too. Thanks. [How to mosaic the same HDF files using R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628501/how-to-mosaic-the-same-hdf-files-using-r)

Comment: @maRtin . Hi maRtin, Could you please have a look to this question, too. Thanks. [How to mosaic the same HDF files using R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628501/how-to-mosaic-the-same-hdf-files-using-r)